# Accessing element of a dictionary array in Python (Hashed Arrays)

Tags: python, arrays, hash

Don't use python much, so not sure of the syntax. I created and loaded a hased array with this command in a loop.

```
dataHash2020.setdefault(hashString,[]).append(cellObj.value)
```

I'm using a key "hashString" and then I append into the array associated with it. But my struggle is how do I access the first, second, etc, element in the array?

I have tried various syntax but nothing seems to work.

```
dataHash2020[hashString].[0] 
dataHash2020[hashString].keys()[0] 
dataHash2020[hashString][0]
```

I can't find the right method to access the first element. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is `dataHash2020`? can we see how you create it?

Comment: `dataHash2020[hashString][0]` should be correct.

Comment: FYI, in Python these are called lists, not arrays.

Comment: What happens when you execute *dataHash2020[hashString][0]* ? Your first attempt is syntactically incorrect. Your second attempt will fail at runtime with AttributeError because lists don't have a *keys()* function. Your third attempt is syntactically correct and if there is at least one value in the list it will work. If the list is empty you'll see IndexError

Comment: I had a . between the ][ so it didn't work! The third version does work. Sadly when I typed out the question I did it right, but left it wrong in the code! Thanks for the help. @interjay if you write it as an answer I'll approve it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was provided by interjay.

`dataHash2020[hashString][0]` is the correct syntax.